# Malwarebytes for Linux

Tags: ubuntu

I am looking for something for linux/gnome along the lines of Malwarebytes' ip blocker. Basically use a blacklist and block http requests if one of those ips/domains are called. I know Firefox blacklists but I know on my Windows 7 machine that the Malwarebytes' ip blocker caught a lot of things that Firefox's didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like Moblock:

http://moblock-deb.sourceforge.net/

With a Gui:

http://mobloquer.foutrelis.com/

You can add all kinds of lists from [iblocklist.com](http://www.iblocklist.com/lists.php), and create your own.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Wow I didn't realize this question was so old... it was near the top of the site...

Comment: The community user bumps unanswered older questions from time to time. But this is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomplicated FireWall (UFW) is ubuntu's equivalent tool.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW

Comment: That is a firewall and yes I use iptables already. I am looking for something that does malwarebytes blacklisting ability.

Comment: Isn't blacklisting the point of a firewall? I guess there's iplist if you want a GUI http://iplist.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Maybe you could be more specific, for people who aren't familiar with MalwareBytes' blacklisting?  It sounds a lot like a firewall from what you said